# jquery form required on specific submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one `<form>` with two submit buttons. I want to set my Title as required on one submit button, but not the other one. Right now it works on the one I dont need.

Button that is at the end of the form and required works:

```
<button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

Button that is in the middle of form and required does not work:

```
 <button type="submit" id="submitformat"  class="btn">Add format</button>
```

JS:

```
$("#submitformat").click(function( event ) {
   $("#required").prop('required',true);
}
 the required field:
 <input type="text" id="required" name="title"/>
```

Comment: where is `required`??

Comment: What is the version of the jQuery that you're using ?

Comment: as far as i understood your question , i believe u should bind click event on button with id `submit`

Comment: You're missing a parenthesis after wiring the event. Add `);`

Comment: **Id's should be unique**. Your #required suggests your using the same id on multiple inputs, this is invalid HTML and breaks Jquery.

Comment: @Liam He has two buttons and one input field. If he submits with button 1, he wants the input to be required. If he submits with the other button, he wants the input NOT to be required.

Answer (score 0):

You need to *remove* the `required` property when you use the other button:

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    $("#required").removeProp('required');
});
```

Otherwise it may still have the `required` property that was set when you clicked the `#submitformat` button.

Comment: This disabled the required but still its not required for right submit

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that required field is below first submit button?